# Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener

Tags: struts2, tiles

I am trying to integrate `Tiles3.0.3` with Struts2, but I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<context-param>
<param-name>
  org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
</param-name>
<param-value>
  /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
 <listener>
<listener-class>
  org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
</listener-class>
</listener>    
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>example/HelloWorld.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here is my tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
  "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="title"  value="Template"/>
  <put-attribute name="banner" value="/banner.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="menu"   value="/menu.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/body.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="footer"   value="/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
<definition name="tiger" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title"  value="Tiger"/>
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/tiger.jsp"/>      
</definition>

<definition name="lion" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title"  value="Lion"/>
  <put-attribute name="body"   value="/lion.jsp"/>      
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

And these are the errors I am getting

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 52 more
```

And these are the jars which I am using :-
`commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar`,`commons-digester-1.7.jar`,`struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar`,
`tiles-api-3.0.3.jar`,`tiles-compat-3.0.3.jar`, `tiles-core-3.0.3.jar`, `tiles-jsp-3.0.3.jar,tiles-servlet-3.0.3.jar`

Please help me out.

Comment: For Tiles3 there is `struts2-tiles3-plugin` since Struts2 `2.3.9`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have tiles jar in your web-inf/classes.

If your project is maven enabled use below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download struts-tiles plugin and tiles plugin jars manualy

Comment: I did that but still not working. i just can not figure out why it cant find StrutsTilesListener

Comment: Actually TilesListener class which extended by StrutsTilesListener is not available in any package thats why NoClassDefFoundError is encountered. but it still can not figure out how to overcome it

Comment: May be you maven is not configured try to review http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_tiles.htm it mentioned all required jars you can add them manually